# Rails / Jquery: When loading a page how to see a spinning wheel?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi guys I'm new to jquery and I just setup some AJAX page loading in my rails app. So far I have a menu that loads different requests inside a container div using AJAX. However, when I click a link to load the new page inside the div, there is a delay where I'm still looking at the old page before the new one loads.

I've seen elsewhere people use a spinning wheel animation to signify the loading, here's an example site that does it when you click the 'show notes' 'comments' or 'similar episodes' links http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised

Thanks for any help!

Edit: more details about more rails website.

The root page has a container div that by default contains an array of objects.

Then I have a menu that loads an ajax request and replaces the contents of div.stream with the result.

This means that I can't have the div.stream contain a default 'Loading please wait message'

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a GIF image that you display on a div using position: absolute and you show the div before making the AJAX request and hide it when the AJAX request is completed.

Here's a live example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8sPZ/), I'm using "setTimeout" to simulate a 3 second long AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.There is just aimage which in shown in container dive and gets replaced with ajax response when it's ready.

You  have container div to show contents.

Show by default show loading anination image in lt like

```
<div id="container" >
    <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />
</div>
```

As content fetching process completes and ur Html to content is ready

Replace div inner HTML with page content.

```
<div id="container" >
   Replace image with Page content after fetching data ajax/jquery response
</div>
```

You can also use ajaxStart/Stop functions like below:

```
$('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">
    Loading Please Wait....
    <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />
</div>
```